# Why does Coq restrict Inductive definitions, and how is this related to Inaccessible cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, type-theory, coq

Coq lets you define an inductive type of the following form:

```
Inductive Foo :=
  | Base : Foo
  | Positive : (nat -> Foo) -> Foo.
```

because the position of `Foo` in the premise of the `Positive` constructor is considered by Coq to be a *positive* position.

Coq rejects an inductive definition where the type being defined appears in a *negative* position in a premise. Accepting such a definition would enable the construction of non-normalizing terms. In particular, it is not possible to create an induction principle for such a definition.

For example:

```
Inductive SnaFoo :=
  | Negative : (SnaFoo -> nat) -> SnaFoo.
```

is rejected with the error message:

```
Error: Non strictly positive occurrence of "SnaFoo" in "((SnaFoo -> nat) -> nat) -> SnaFoo".
```

But Coq also rejects the following definition:

```
Inductive Bar :=
  | IsItPositive : ((Bar -> nat) -> nat) -> Bar.
```

The position of `Bar` in the premise of the `IsItPositive` constructor is not obviously positive but I have seen a presentation (sorry, I can no longer find the link) that accepted this position as positive. I could formulate a plausible inductive principle for `Bar` as follows:

```
Definition Bar_ind (P : Bar -> Prop) :=
  (forall (F : (Bar -> nat) -> nat),
    (forall f g, (forall (b : Bar), P b -> f b = g b) -> F f = F g)
    -> P (IsItPositive F))
  -> forall (b : Bar), P b.
```

More importantly, assuming the existence of enough inaccessible cardinals, I think I can prove that there is a model of Coq's type theory that contains inductive types like `Bar`, with the inductive principle that I proposed. I did prove that the presence of $\omega^2$ inaccessibles is enough to accommodate `Bar` itself, assuming that all the other inductive types in the model conform to Coq's positivity rules. I don't know how many inaccessibles will be required to relax the positivity assumptions of Coq in general.

My question is twofold:

First, what is the reason that Coq does not admit definitions like `Bar`?

Second, what is a good reference for the topic of admissibility of inductive types?

Comment: You should write "inductive type" or "inductive family" instead of "induction-recursion". That means [something else](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inductive-recursive+type). None of your examples here are inductive-recursive.

Comment: I took the liberty of renaming things. We don't want faulty nomenclature to spill over into the math community.

Comment: You might be better off searching for an answer at https://cstheory.stackexchange.com, where such questions are discussed periodically. For example, the answers to [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/42627/intuition-behind-strict-positivity) has several useful references.

Comment: Thanks András. I had a misconception about the meaning of the term.

Comment: By the way, how do you prove the existtence of a **non-trivial** `Bar` using inaccessibles? As soon as `Bar` has more than one element, the cardinality of $(B \to \mathbb{N}) \to mathbb{N}$ will exceed that of $B$.

Comment: Terminology-wise, I think the occurrence of `Bar` in `IsItPositive` is generally conceded to be *positive*, but not *strictly positive*, and strict positivity is the standard requirement of constructors of inductive types.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming classical definite description there is a function

```
decide : forall {A : Prop} (P : A -> Prop), A -> nat
```

s.t.

```
(decide P x = 1 <-> P x) /\ (decide P x = 0 <-> ~ P x)
```

It follows under the assumption of propositional extensionality that, moreover

```
forall A (P Q : Q -> Prop), decide P = decide Q <-> (forall x, P x = Q x)
```

---

Thus, we would have

```
Definition contains_power (P : Bar -> Prop) : Bar := IsItPositive (fun x => decide P x).
```

Which would be injective.

As such, your type includes its own power set, which violates Cantor's theorem. For a more detailed account of the argument where `Prop` replaces `nat`, see https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/core/inductive.html in the paragraph "it is less obvious why"

I know not how much of the classical argument here is needed to produce a contradiction, but it seems to me unlikely that there is a sets-and-functions model which has your `Bar` type in it (assuming, at least, that what ever large cardinals you need are consistent). But, I could imagine that there might be an alternative model, however, that exploits some of the constructive structure of the type theory--maybe this is what you have cooked up?

Comment: I think classicality isn't necessary to derive a contradiction; all you need is propositional resizing.  There's an argument to this effect in section 5.6 of the [HoTT Book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/).